# Django: Filter on related model's field not being equal to a specific value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Given these models:

```py
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    pass  # table with only one column, i.e. a primary key 'id' of type integer

class Bar(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bars')
```

How to create a filter which returns all `Foo`s related to *at least one* `Bar` with *a non-zero* `value`?

I am aware that it is possible to at first select the non-zero `Bar`s and then return the `Foo`s related to them. But I am specifically looking for a solution which obtains the relevant `Foo`s in a QuerySet directly. The reason is that it it could then easily be applied to relationships which are nested to a deeper level.

---

### What does not work

It is straightforward to create a QuerySet which returns all `Foo`s related to at least one `Bar` with a *zero* `value`:

```py
Foo.objects.filter(bars__value="zero")
```

However, due to the lack of the "not equal" operator in Django's filter methods, it is impossible to do something like this:

```
Foo.objects.filter(bars__value__not_equal="zero")  # Unsupported lookup 'not_equal' for TextField
```

Using `exclude`:

```py
Foo.objects.exclude(bars__value="zero")
```

does not produce the desired output because it excludes all `Foo`s which relate to *at least one* `Bar` with a zero value.

So, if a `Foo` is related to two `Bar`s, one of which has a zero `value` and the other has a non-zero `value`, it would be filtered out by this `exclude`. The intention is, however, to include it because it is related to at least one `Bar` with a non-zero value.

Similarly, using the negated `Q` object:

```py
Foo.objects.filter(~models.Q(bars__value="zero"))
```

also does not produce the desired output because it would only include all `Foo`s which are *not* related to *any* `Bar`s with a zero value.

It would create the same QuerySet as the `exclude` method mentioned above.

---

#### Notes

The type of the `B.value` field has intentionally been chosen as text in the examples to emphasize that I am looking for a generic solution where the "not equal" operator cannot be emulated by using e.g. a combination of "less than" and "greater than" operators.

Answer (score 0):

I also can't think of a simple way of achieving this, but using a `Subquery` to exclude zero-value `Bar`s might work:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

qs = Foo.objects.filter(
    bars__pk__in=Subquery(Bar.objects.exclude(value="zero").values('pk'))
)
```

This should give you all `Foo` instances with a relation to a `Bar` with non-zero value.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but examining all `Bar`s in a subquery is inefficient, especially in case when the outer QuerySet of `Foo` objects is already restricted by some other filtering criteria. If possible, I would like to use an approach that is reasonably efficient in those cases as well.

Comment: Note that the subquery is never evaluated as a normal queryset would be. It is only passed as an instruction to the database which is capable of performing the query efficiently, especially if you have proper indexes set. I would be thankful if you share a more performant solution that satisfies all requirements if you find one.